# vba code for looping solver selectively crashes excel?

Tags: vba, excel, crash, solver

I have an issue I was hoping someone could help with. I put together some vba code to have excel loop solver (set to the evolutionary method). The code is as follows:

```
Sub Repeat_Solver()

    Worksheets("DC Ranking by CM (All DC costs)").Activate
    limit = 148
    i = 147

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Do Until i = limit

        If Range("BV" & i).Value = "Y" Then

            SolverReset

            SolverOk SetCell:="$EQ$" & i, MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$CA$" & i, _
                     Engine:=3, EngineDesc:="Evolutionary"

            SolverAdd CellRef:="$CG$" & i, Relation:=3, FormulaText:="45"
            SolverAdd CellRef:="$CH$" & i, Relation:=1, FormulaText:="0.4"
            SolverAdd CellRef:="$CA$" & i, Relation:=1, FormulaText:="$E$" & i
            SolverAdd CellRef:="$CA$" & i, Relation:=4, FormulaText:="integer"

            SolverOptions MaxTime:=60, Iterations:=200, Precision:=0.000001, _
                          AssumeLinear:=False, StepThru:=False, Estimates:=1, _
                          Derivatives:=1, SearchOption:=1, IntTolerance:=1, _
                          Scaling:=False, Convergence:=0.000001, AssumeNonNeg:=True, _
                          PopulationSize:=100, RandomSeed:=0, MutationRate:=0.075, _
                          Multistart:=False, RequireBounds:=False, MaxSubproblems:=3, _
                          MaxIntegerSols:=2, SolveWithout:=False, MaxTimeNoImp:=30

            SolverOk SetCell:="$EQ$" & i, MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$CA$" & i, _
                     Engine:=3, EngineDesc:="Evolutionary"

            SolverOk SetCell:="$EQ$" & i, MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$CA$" & i, _
                     Engine:=3, EngineDesc:="Evolutionary"

            SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
            SolverFinish KeepFinal:=1
            i = i + 1

        Else
            i = i + 1
        End If

    Loop

End Sub
```

When I set `limit=147` and `i=146` (to run it just for row 146), it works - but for some strange reason, when I run it for `limit=148` and `i=147` (as in the code above), it stalls on 'setting up problem ... 33%' and then excel stops responding.

I even tried running solver manually on line 147 (without the vba code), but still the same problem - excel crashes. (It does seems to work, strangely enough, if I set solver to GRG Nonlinear, instead of evolutionary.)

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance for your help!